# How do I get the Device dropdown to show up in the top line next to the app dropdown

Tags: linux, windows, android-studio

Android Studio -- Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1
I want to run the app on my connected device.
How do I get the Device dropdown to show up in the top line next to the app dropdown.
It has been there before but I lost it (I think) during an Android Studio upgrade.
I am showing two apps below. I am not showing the Project Files on the left.
The Device dropdown shows up in the top app but not the bottom app.
I have clicked on Device Manager > Physical > ? 
which brings up a screen "Run apps on a hardware device"
I connect to a USB port.
On the device I select System > Developer Options [On] and USB Debugging [On]
The device(s) show up under Device Manager.
On the top app you see two dropdowns on the top line [app ] and [LGE VS998 ] 
I can click on the right arrow next to the [LGE VS998 ] dropdown and my app will start on the device.
On the bottom app you only see [app ] dropdown but no [device ] dropdown and I can't run the app on a device.
I get the same result on Linux Ubuntu GNOME and Windows 10

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After spending a week unable to resolve this, I went with plan B.
I renamed my non-functioning app to move it out of the way.
I started with a new project, empty application, and used my original non-functioning app name.
It started with the [app] and [device} dropdowns in the top line. YEA !!
After it ran with "Hello World" on the screen, I spent an hour copying my code to this new app.
Other than deleting a theme with some colors I wasn't using -- Success.
I can now select a device and run the app on that device.
This plan B does not answer the question but it solved my problem.
So, I will leave it unmarked for the answer and hope someone can find the answer.
Thank you and Peace.